# Initialize an array using size defined by parameter in verilog

Tags: verilog

can we initialize arrays using parameter to define size in verilog
for example I want

```
parameter max_neigh=8 , size = 72;
reg [0:8*max_neigh-1]neighbors = size'h010203040304050607;
//or as
reg [0:8*max_neigh-1]neighbors = (8*max_neigh-1)'h010203040304050607;
```

It gives error: "syntax error near 'h".
 Any help will be highly appreciated!
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Declaring arrays with parametrized does not generate any problem.
However from what I know you cannot use a parametrized size for a value assignment. 
You can instead leave the 'size' field empty.

It would look like:

`reg [0:8*max_neigh-1]neighbors = 'h010203040304050607;`

If you absolutely want to use your `size` parameter you can do something like:

`reg [0:8*max_neigh-1]neighbors = {size{1'b0}};`

Which would duplicate the `1'b0` value `size` in the array, which would be equivalent to `72'h000000000000000000`.

**BONUS**

Be aware that such assignment cannot be synthesised. 
This is worse than that in fact, the synthesis tool would not report an error, maybe a warning, but simply ignore that assignment.
To initialize a register you should use a process.

For example a synchronous process would be with clk a clock input and nrst a reset signal that is active on low-level:

```
reg [0:8*max_neigh-1]neighbors;
wire [0:8*max_neigh-1]next_neighbors_value;
always@(posedge clk or negedge nrst)
    if(~nrst)
        neighbors <= {72{1'b0}};
    else
        neighbors <= next_neighbors_value;
```

And btw, 8*8 = 64 and not 72.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply and bonus !   but initializing as 'h010203040304050607   does only takes the last 32 bits of the number. {size{1'b0}} initialize by zero. Rather I want to initialize it by the desired number.

Comment: Sorry for the multiplication mistake. I realized it after posting my question

Comment: A bold way to do it would be to choose a huge size for the handwritten value 1024 bits for example. if you do not write all the bits, they will be replaced by 0 and it will give you some space to specify your value without risking Xs in the register.

Comment: I didn't know about the 32bits thing, noted.
Another solution came to my mind: if there is a pattern in your initial value, you could use some for/while loops like in software programming. 
But it generally cannot be synthetised...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to put a size on a hexadecimal(or any base) number as long as you only care that it be extended by zeros and won't be used in a bit-wise expression where the actual size matters(~'h1 is not a good idea).